Export encountered errors on following paths:
 Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /(main)/blocks/page: /blocks
        /(main)/components/maintable/page: /components/maintable
        /(main)/documentation/page: /documentation
        /(main)/page: /
        /(main)/pages/crud/page: /pages/crud
        /(main)/pages/empty/page: /pages/empty
        /(main)/pages/timeline/page: /pages/timeline
        /(main)/uikit/groups/page: /uikit/groups
        /(main)/uikit/lessons/page: /uikit/lessons
        /(main)/uikit/teachers/page: /uikit/teachers
        /(main)/utilities/icons/page: /utilities/icons
        /component/modals/delete_modal/page: /component/modals/delete_modal

I got this error when I build nextjs. But everything is written correctly and clearly, that is, there are no errors in the code
I have tried all the solutions on the internet but no clear result and the error is not enabled. I downloaded a ready-made template from the Internet and modified it, and it was showing this error
